# Hibernate - query 2 tables

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have the following hibernate query and it is always returning null from the database:

```
em.createQuery("SELECT ms FROM MovieSuggestion ms"
                    + " WHERE movie.imdbId = :imdbId")
```

What it is supposed to do is, from a `MovieSuggestion` model, see if there are any `Movie` models with the certain `imdbId` (`imdbId` is not the primary key).

So basically - `Movie` has a non-primary key attribute `imdbId`, and I am supposed to find if there are any `Movies` in `MovieSuggestions` based on that `imdbId`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, this should work

```
em.createQuery("FROM MovieSuggestion ms WHERE ms.movie.imdbId = :imdbId")
```

This is under assumption that `MovieSuggestion` has a field `movie`.

Comment: Znaci kopirano sa skype sto sam slao kolegi prije sat vremena: 
"FROM MovieSuggestion ms WHERE ms.movie.imdbId = :imdbId" 
i nije radilo...hvala druze.

Comment: Ko zna, bitno da sad radi. Nema na cemu, pozdrav